# Interleaving WAI streaming with safe-pipes

Tags: http, haskell, streaming, haskell-pipes, haskell-wai

I'm using pipes and WAI to stream audio. The problem is that I need to lookahead some data in safe-pipe, then choose response headers based on extracted information, and then continue streaming that pipe as the response body. Here is what I have now and what works fine:

```
respond $ Wai.responseStream status200 headers $ \write flush -> do
    runSafeT $ runEffect $ do
        (mph, chunks) <- lift $ Mpeg.headerFromPipe pipe
        for chunks $ \chunk -> liftIO $ do
            write $ BB.byteString chunk
            flush
```

`respond` is standard [Application](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.3.0/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application)'s funarg, and `Mpeg.headerFromPipe` is my looking-ahead computation:

```
respond :: Response -> IO ResponseReceived

Mpeg.headerFromPipe :: Monad m 
    => Producer ByteString m r
    -> m (Mpeg.Header, Producer ByteString m r)

pipe :: Producer ByteString (SafeT IO) ()

Wai.responseStream :: Status -> ResponseHeaders -> StreamingBody -> Response

type StreamingBody = (Builder -> IO ()) -> IO () -> IO ()
```

So the question: is there any way to move `respond` between `headerFromPipe` and `for` to use `mph` to choose headers to give to [`responseStream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.3.0/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:responseStream). I can't tear apart `headerFromPipe` and `for` into two different [SafeT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-safe-2.2.3/docs/Pipes-Safe.html#t:SafeT)-computation threads because then first `runSafeT` will finalize the pipe and `chunks` pipe (which is the result of performing [`next`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.5/docs/Pipes.html#v:next) few times, inspecting data, yielding stuff back and chaining with the remainder) will fail.